# Existence of a linear map with a given minimal polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, minimal-polynomials

Let $F$ be a ﬁeld, $V$ an $n$-dimensional $F$-vector space, and $f(T) \in F[T]$ a monic polynomial of degree $n \geq 1$. Show that there exists a $F$-linear map $\alpha : V \rightarrow V$ whose minimal polynomial is $f(T)$.

I'm not quite sure where to even begin. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's a bit easier if $F$ is an algebraically closed field. Then you have to look at appropriate Jordan blocks taking into account the multiplicity of each of the eigenvalues of $T$.

Comment: Look up "companion matrix" in Wikipedia.

Comment: And ignore all this silly chat about eigenvalues, algebraic closure, Jordan blocks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lord Shark the Unknown states in the comments, the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of $f$ has $f$ as its minimal polynomial.  This matrix arises in a natural way by considering the $F[T]$-module $F[T]/(f(T))$.  Write $f(T) = T^n + a_{n-1} T^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0$.  By the division algorithm, $1, T, \ldots, T^{n-1}$ is an $F$-basis for $F[T]/(f(T))$, and the action of $T$ can described simply with respect to this basis:
\begin{align*}
T \cdot T^i =
\begin{cases}
T^{i+1} & \text{if } i = 0, \ldots, n-2\\
- a_0 - a_1T - \cdots - a_{n-1} T^{n-1} & \text{if } i = n-1 \, .
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Thus with respect to the given basis, the $F$-linear map of multiplication by $T$ has matrix
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -a_0\\
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -a_1 \\
0 & 1 & & 0 & -a_2 \\
\vdots & & \ddots & & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & & 1 & -a_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix} \, .
\end{align*}
This is called the companion matrix of $f$.  For more on the companion matrix and its role in rational canonical form, see $\S12.2$ of Dummit and Foote.